# coq proof : tactic absurd, how does it works?

Tags: coq

I am trying to understand a proof in coq. I wrote it long ago during a course but now I'm blocked by the absurd command. 
Here is the proof :

```
Theorem Thm_2 : (~psi -> ~phi) -> (phi -> psi).
Proof.
intro.
intro.
cut (psi \/ ~psi).
intro.
elim H1.
intro.
exact H2.
intro.
absurd phi.
cut (~psi).
exact H.
exact H2.
exact H0.
apply classic.
Qed.
```

When I use the absurd phi tactic, my current goal is psi. And the absurd command transforms it in two goals : ~ phi and phi. 
My problem is I can't figure nor remember the logic behind this step...

Thank you for your help !
(it seems I can't add a Hello at the beginning of my message... sorry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If you can prove `phi` and `~ phi`, then you can prove `False` (remember, `~ phi := phi -> False`)
- If you can prove `False`, then you can prove anything, including your goal at that point

So `absurd phi` applies `False` elimination, and have you prove `False` by means of proving both `phi` and `~ phi`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ptival! but I still don't understand completly. If I prove false with the hypothesis of theorem my  doesn't it means that it is wrong ?  Thanks for your help !

Comment: Most of the time you use `absurd` in only on sub-proof of a theorem, to discard a "impossible" branch. For example with euclidean division: `forall a b:nat, b <> 0 -> exists q:nat, exists r:nat, a = b * q + r` you might use `absurd` whenever your consider the case `b = 0` (this example is too simple in practice, but you get the main idea).